# When would I use express-validator over @hapi/joi?

Tags: node.js, express

I've implemented my code base using @hapi/joi, but I've recently come across express-validator, which appears to do all the same stuff, but is a lot simpler to use. I've reviewed some of the questions here on this topic, but they're mostly dated.

I realize this may be subjective, but when would you recommend I use express-validator over @hapi/joi? Maybe express-validator just works better b/c I'm using Express, which is what this module was built for.

I'm asking b/c all the tutorials I've used make use of @hapi/joi and I can't understand why. Maybe I'm missing something obvious.

What I really like about express-validator is how easy it is to use sanitation in Express routes and barring anyone having problems w/it, I may switch permanently. @hapi/joi has this ability too, but it's harder to implement IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Gary.
`hapi/joi` allows you to create a blueprint for your validation, while `express-validator` uses the `validator.js`.
Obviously while working with express projects, you'll find express-validator can be used out of the box, without much configuration, and that is exactly where I will use `express-validator`.
When I need to set up validation for my requests, and I'm not much bothered about the level of customization and readability in my `Validating params`.

If you want to see a critical approach and comparison between the two, there's a great blog by 101node.io: [https://101node.io/blog/javascript-validators-comparison-using-joi-vs-express-validator/#:~:text=express%2Dvalidator%20is%20a%20set,js%20middlewares%20that%20wraps%20validator.&text=Joi%20can%20be%20used%20for,library%20and%20easy%20to%20use](https://101node.io/blog/javascript-validators-comparison-using-joi-vs-express-validator/#:%7E:text=express%2Dvalidator%20is%20a%20set,js%20middlewares%20that%20wraps%20validator.&text=Joi%20can%20be%20used%20for,library%20and%20easy%20to%20use)

Happy Coding !

Comment: Thanks Ashutosh, I read the article. While it does provide helpful illustrations of how to do things, I'm still left w/my original question - when should I use joi over express-validator? Joi is amazing for validation, but sanitation is difficult to implement and I don't want two libs when express-validator does both. That being said, everyone uses joi - by orders of magnitude more than express-validator. Why?